# How to add a class to a div on a certain option value

Tags: html, jquery, switch-statement, html-select

I was wondering how to add a class to a div if the option has the value selected. For example I'm making a website for my cousin's business, we want an easy way to shuffle through menus.

```
<code>
         <div id="select"><form>
         Menu:
         <select name="select" class="form-control">

           <option value="drinks">Drinks</option>
           <option value="breakfast">Breakfast</option>
         </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
         </form>
</code>
```

I would like if the value is breakfast to hide the div `drinks` and show the div `breakfast`, and also have it reversible. Thank you here's my code on JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/t5R9s/

Comment: @Gurminder Singh has a good jquery solution, I posted a javascript solution. jQuery is cleaner and easier in this case, but I would use javascript unless you're going to utilize more than just the "show" and "hide" features of jquery (you don't have to worry about class names with that.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript. Do you want to do it when you hit submit or just after you make the selection?

[

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t5R9s/3/)

]

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeClass(){
    var myVariable = document.getElementById('control').value;
    if(myVariable == "drinks"){
        document.getElementById('drinks').className = "";
        document.getElementById('breakfast').className = "hide";
    }
    else if(myVariable == "breakfast"){
        document.getElementById('drinks').className = "hide";
        document.getElementById('breakfast').className = "";
    }
}
</script>
<div id="select">
    <form>Menu:
        <select name="select" class="form-control" id="control" onChange="changeClass()">
            <option value="drinks">Drinks</option>
            <option value="breakfast">Breakfast</option>
        </select>
    </form>
</div>
<div id="drinks">
     <h2 align="center">Drinks</h2>

    <table width="888" border="" cellpadding="9" class="">..</table>
</div>
<!--Breakfast table-->
<div id="breakfast" class="hide">
        <h2 align="center">Breakfast</h2>

    <table width="888" border="" cellpadding="9" class="">..</table>
</div>
```

Comment: @undefined lol, yep, I figured I'd tell the how (javascript) and then show what to do to get there later :D

Comment: I tried doing it this way but check it out it doesn't seem to work :/ http://drkmg.us/hummusbar/site

Comment: Please don’t leave placeholder answers in the future. If you have a comment with a possible future answer, leave a comment — you have enough reputation.

Comment: @minitech Haha, wow, can't believe a placeholder that was up for 5 minutes got moderated, lol. I've been late on posting correctly marked answers more than once is why I did that. Thanks for letting me know yall don't like that tho.

Comment: Yeah, people actually did flag it, so :D Don’t worry about making a fast answer, we’ll still vote for you if it’s super amazing!

Answer (score 1):

Here it is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".form-control").change(function() {
  if($(this).val() == "drinks") {
    $("#drinks").show();
    $("#breakfast").hide();
  } else {
    $("#drinks").hide();
    $("#breakfast").show();
  }
 });
});
```

Here is the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/t5R9s/1/).

Comment: may want to change the `else` to `else if` so it will scale easier to more options. Although, I guess there would be a lot more code in that case. ---- That just gave me an idea.

Comment: Yep, but it would only take four characters to make it more scaleable. :D